# Is It Possible To Have One Group Inherit From Another In A Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

If I have a series of gems that are needed in multiple groups, can I have groups inherit from a base group?

I know I can do:

`gem "example", {:groups=>[:group_1, :group_2]}`

Or:

```
group :group_1, :group_2 do
   gem "example"
end
```

But is there a way to do something like:

```
group :base do
   gem "example"
end

group :group_1 < :base do
   …
end

group :group_2 < :base do
   …
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can declare the same group in multiple blocks. They're additive:

```rb
group :group_1, :group_2 do
  gem "example"
end

group :group_1 do
  # extra stuff for group_1
end

group :group_2 do
  # extra stuff for group_2
end
```

Don't think of the group blocks as declaring a group, think of them as declaring that the statements inside the block automatically have the group or groups applied to them.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think grouping inheritance is permitted in Gemfile format.